# Running stored procedure in mysql on new table creation

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to run a stored procedure or something if a new table is created in mysql database. I want to run some set of queries whenever a new table is created.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no event or notification triggered when a new table is created. Hence you cannot act on that step.